# Lua vs Python for bitstamp API. Python code works but not Lua. Why?

Tags: python, lua

My hobby is buying and selling bitcoins trough APIs and I have successfully done so using python by using the "requests" library which also exists for lua. I'm using the bitstamp API. However, my code for lua is not working.

Here's the code for python which works

```
import time
import hashlib
import hmac
import requests
import ast
import pprint

nonce = str(int(time.time()))
customer_id = 'some id'
api_key = 'some string'
API_SECRET = 'some other string'

message = nonce + customer_id + api_key

signature = hmac.new(API_SECRET, msg=message, digestmod=hashlib.sha256).hexdigest().upper()

    # --------------Requests Parameters------------------------

params = {"key": api_key, "signature": signature, 'nonce': nonce}

    # --------------Get Account Balance--------------------------

r = requests.post('https://www.bitstamp.net/api/v2/balance/', data=params)

print(r.text)
```

Now this code works and I get a succesful response.

However my lua code does not work as I get an error from the API so it's not a syntax error apparently. Here's the lua code.

```
requests= require("requests")
openssl = require("openssl")

nonce = tostring(os.time())
customer_id = 'some id'
api_key = 'some string'
API_SECRET = 'some other string'

message = nonce..customer_id..api_key
signature = openssl.hmac.digest('sha256',message,API_SECRET)
signature = string.upper(signature)

print(signature)

params = {['key'] = api_key, ['signature'] = signature, ['nonce'] = nonce}

r = requests.post{"https://www.bitstamp.net/api/v2/balance/", data = params}
print(r.text)
print(r.status_code)
```

The response I get from the server from this code is:

```
{"status": "error", "reason": "Missing key, signature and nonce parameters", "code": "API0000"} 403
```

The value API0000 is an error code from the api(https://www.bitstamp.net/api/) which means "Parameters were not posted in API request"

I just don't know what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: you can send data to http://httpbin.org/post and it will send back all headers, cookies, data from your request so you can compare result from python and from lua

Comment: Thanx furas. Will look into that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using http://httpbin.org/post I see that Lua sends it as `"data"` but Python send it as `"form"` with header `"Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`

I get the same result using

```
params = "key=some string&nonce=1565817138&signature=7DE82CB42D1B8F38F7AC1A74EC3A5E06F1AA3A20A14F3DD0E7040F088FBF9F69"

headers = {["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}

url = "http://httpbin.org/post"
-- url = "https://www.bitstamp.net/api/v2/balance/"

r = requests.post{url, data = params, headers = headers}
```

---

BTW: `params` can't be dictionary/table because it will convert it to

```
"{\"key\":\"some string\",\"nonce\":\"1565888007\", ...
```

and I don't know Lua that well to convert dictionary into expected string.

---

**EDIT:** I created this for converting `params` to correct string

```
params = {['key'] = api_key, ['signature'] = signature, ['nonce'] = nonce}

params_str = {}
for k, v in pairs(params) do 
    table.insert(params_str, k..'='..v)
end
params = table.concat(params_str, '&')

print('params> '..params)
```

Result:

```
params> signature=1492CA16012C0A6F9AAF7DDD66F649FF1DCF0E675D743AEBF77E0E437C8FF006&key=some string&nonce=1565889236
```

---

Full code:

```
requests= require("requests")
openssl = require("openssl")

nonce = tostring(os.time())
customer_id = 'some id'
api_key = 'some string'
API_SECRET = 'some other string'

message = nonce..customer_id..api_key
signature = openssl.hmac.digest('sha256', message, API_SECRET)
signature = string.upper(signature)

params = {['key'] = api_key, ['signature'] = signature, ['nonce'] = nonce}

params_str = {}
for k, v in pairs(params) do 
    table.insert(params_str, k..'='..v)
end
params = table.concat(params_str, '&')

-- params = "key=some string&nonce=1565817138&signature=7DE82CB42D1B8F38F7AC1A74EC3A5E06F1AA3A20A14F3DD0E7040F088FBF9F69"
print('params> '..params)

url = "http://httpbin.org/post"
-- url = "https://www.bitstamp.net/api/v2/balance/"

headers = {["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}

r = requests.post{url, data = params, headers = headers}
print(r.text)
print(r.status_code)
```

Comment: You got it. That solved my problem. This Lua code is working perfectly now with bitstamp. Thanx for your effort as i have a bit more understanding in lua now.